# Ruby on rails 4, set routes.rb and resources do

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, routes

I don't know how to set up more then 1 "item" in resources do method. I have 3 scaffolds, i.e. Post, Comment, Response. I want to reach that in rake routes: 'new_post_comment_response => /posts/id/comment/id/response/new'

The relations are:

'Post model
has many :comments 
has many :responses

Comment model
has many :responses
belongs_to :post

Response model
belongs_to :post
belongs_to :comment'

In routes.rb I have set:

resources :posts do
resources :comments, except: [:show, :index]
end

resources :comments do
resources :responses, except: [:show, :index]
end

But I want to have three items in rake routes, because i'm going to do something a "three responses in forums (Post-Comment-Response-to-comment)". Do you know what I mean?

So, my question is: how to set up resources and controllers to detect Post and Comment ID, and how to set up resources.

Thanks for help!

Comment: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.9/routing.html#nested-resources have you checked out this

Answer (score 1):

You basically just need to nest the resources in the way that you wish them to be. That means Posts should have nested Comments and Responses and Comments should have nested Responses. You could probably set it up something along the lines of this, assuming I read your requirements correctly.

```
concern :responsable do
  resources :responses, except: [:show, :index]
end

resources :posts, concerns: :responsable do
  resources :comments, except: [:show, :index],  concerns: :responsable
end
```

The concern is simply a way of reusing a set of common routes. More about it is in the [documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html).

If you run rake routes you should end up with the following paths:

```
    post_comment_responses POST   /posts/:post_id/comments/:comment_id/responses(.:format)          responses#create
 new_post_comment_response GET    /posts/:post_id/comments/:comment_id/responses/new(.:format)      responses#new
edit_post_comment_response GET    /posts/:post_id/comments/:comment_id/responses/:id/edit(.:format) responses#edit
     post_comment_response PATCH  /posts/:post_id/comments/:comment_id/responses/:id(.:format)      responses#update
                           PUT    /posts/:post_id/comments/:comment_id/responses/:id(.:format)      responses#update
                           DELETE /posts/:post_id/comments/:comment_id/responses/:id(.:format)      responses#destroy
             post_comments POST   /posts/:post_id/comments(.:format)                                comments#create
          new_post_comment GET    /posts/:post_id/comments/new(.:format)                            comments#new
         edit_post_comment GET    /posts/:post_id/comments/:id/edit(.:format)                       comments#edit
              post_comment PATCH  /posts/:post_id/comments/:id(.:format)                            comments#update
                           PUT    /posts/:post_id/comments/:id(.:format)                            comments#update
                           DELETE /posts/:post_id/comments/:id(.:format)                            comments#destroy
            post_responses POST   /posts/:post_id/responses(.:format)                               responses#create
         new_post_response GET    /posts/:post_id/responses/new(.:format)                           responses#new
        edit_post_response GET    /posts/:post_id/responses/:id/edit(.:format)                      responses#edit
             post_response PATCH  /posts/:post_id/responses/:id(.:format)                           responses#update
                           PUT    /posts/:post_id/responses/:id(.:format)                           responses#update
                           DELETE /posts/:post_id/responses/:id(.:format)                           responses#destroy
                     posts GET    /posts(.:format)                                                  posts#index
                           POST   /posts(.:format)                                                  posts#create
                  new_post GET    /posts/new(.:format)                                              posts#new
                 edit_post GET    /posts/:id/edit(.:format)                                         posts#edit
                      post GET    /posts/:id(.:format)                                              posts#show
                           PATCH  /posts/:id(.:format)                                              posts#update
                           PUT    /posts/:id(.:format)                                              posts#update
                           DELETE /posts/:id(.:format)                                              posts#destroy
```